# using pandas.read_csv to read certain columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a .csv file with three columns and many rows. I am trying to use pandas to read only the third column.

right now I have:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv(r"C:\test.csv",usecols=(3))
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

column indexing is zero based, pass `2` to read the third column:

```
pd.read_csv(r"C:\test.csv",usecols=[2])
```

Comment: Not to add much to this answer, but of course, you can select various columns, as I did here:

    df =  pd.read_csv(
        '.\\file.csv', 
        usecols=[0,1,2,3,5])

Answer (score 6):

Adding on to @EdChum answer, you can also simply use `range`

`pd.read_csv(r"C:\test.csv",usecols=range(5))`

to read the first 5 columns. If you columns aren't numeric you can always use `header=None` to have pandas ignore the columns