# Load only first two columns from CSV file using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df of the following format:

```
       0          A           84         13.0          69.0   ...  45
       1          B           76         77.0          127.0  ...  55
       2          C           28         69.0          16.0   ...  66
       3          D           28         28.0          31.0   ...  44
```

shape is: 160,000 X 20000

I'm not able to load the entire dataframe into memory. Also I only need to read the first two columns into memory. How should one go about this? Note that I don't have any column names to use use_cols

Comment: does this help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716643/using-pandas-read-csv-to-read-certain-columns

Comment: @DaSong Taking a long time, still not loaded. is it loading the entire dataframe?

Comment: You can try to use standard `csv` module and load only the first two columns

Comment: @AndrejKesely If you can provide the answer below, i can verify it with tick so that it's useful for future readers

Comment: @Neo I posted an example

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
import csv

data = []
with open("your_data.csv", "r") as f_in:
    csvreader = csv.reader(
        f_in
    )  # configure reader here, for example separator, quotechars

    # skip headers (if any)
    next(csvreader)

    for col1, col2, *_ in csvreader:
        data.append([col1, col2])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["col1", "col2"])
print(df)
```